# Como substutuir um layout por outro no QHBoxlayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pyqt, pyqt-5

Criei dois QGridLayout, com 16 botões cada, numerados de 1 a 32. Armazenei os dois QGridLayout em uma lista (um em cada posição da lista). Essa lista é inserida em um QHBoxLayout para apresentar os botões na tela. Além dessa lista com dois layouts de botões, existem mais dois botões (next/previous) que será usado para trocar o índice da lista e, por consequência, trocar os botões apresentados na tela. A ideia é que a lista de layout funcione como paginas e os botões next e previous troque essas paginas sempre que forem pressionados.
 Após o programa rodar e apresentar o primeiro layout de botões (1 a 16), ao pressionar o botão next o índice da lista é incrementado e a "página" é trocada apresentando o outro layout de botões (17 a 32), mas quando eu pressiono o botão previous a "página" não troca. O índice da lista é decrementado, mas não troca os botões.
Como resolver esse problema?

Abaixo Pagina 1 da lista:

[image: Pagina 1]

Abaixo Pagina 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Page Buttons'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 225
        self.height = 225
        self.count_pages = 0
        self.pages_grid_list = [];  # pages list
        self.h_layout = None

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        count = 0
        for count_pages in range(0, 2):

            page_btns_grid_layout = QGridLayout()  # create page

            for x in range(0, 4):
                for y in range(0, 4):
                    print("page: {} - row: {} - column: {}".format(count_pages , x, y))

                    count = count + 1
                    button = QPushButton(str(count))
                    button.clicked.connect(self.get_coordinates_btn_clicked)

                    page_btns_grid_layout.addWidget(button, x, y, Qt.AlignCenter)

            self.pages_grid_list.append(page_btns_grid_layout)  # add page in pages list

        next_page_button = QPushButton('next')
        next_page_button.clicked.connect(self.next_page_action)

        previous_page_button = QPushButton('previous')
        previous_page_button.clicked.connect(self.previous_page_action)

        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(previous_page_button, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.h_layout.addLayout(self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages])
        self.h_layout.addWidget(next_page_button, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.show()

    def get_coordinates_btn_clicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        page_btns = self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages]  # get current page to get coordinate button clicked
        idx = page_btns.indexOf(button)
        location = page_btns.getItemPosition(idx)
        print('coordinates: {}'.format(location[:2]))

    def next_page_action(self):
        self.count_pages = self.count_pages + 1

        if self.count_pages < len(self.pages_grid_list):
            old_page = self.h_layout.itemAt(1)  # get old page
            self.h_layout.removeItem(old_page)  # remove old page of current layout
            new_page = self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages]  # change page
            self.h_layout.insertLayout(1, new_page)  # add new next page in current layout
        else:
            self.count_pages = len(self.pages_grid_list) - 1

    def previous_page_action(self):
        self.count_pages = self.count_pages - 1

        if self.count_pages >= 0:
            old_page = self.h_layout.itemAt(1)  # get old page
            self.h_layout.removeItem(old_page)  # remove old page of current layout
            new_page = self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages]  # change page
            self.h_layout.insertLayout(1, new_page)  # add new previous page in current layout
        else:
            self.count_pages = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Estou usando Python 3.7, PyQt5 5.14.2 e Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Page Buttons'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 225
        self.height = 225
        self.count_pages = 0
        self.pages_grid_list = [];                                       # pages list QWidget
        self.h_layout = None

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        count = 0
        for count_pages in range(0, 2):

            page_btns_grid_widget = QWidget()                                # +++ QWidget
            page_btns_grid_layout = QGridLayout(page_btns_grid_widget)       # + page_btns_grid_widget

            for x in range(0, 4):
                for y in range(0, 4):
                    print("page: {} - row: {} - column: {}".format(count_pages , x, y))

                    count = count + 1
                    button = QPushButton(str(count))
                    button.clicked.connect(self.get_coordinates_btn_clicked)

                    page_btns_grid_layout.addWidget(button, x, y, Qt.AlignCenter)

#            self.pages_grid_list.append(page_btns_grid_layout)               # add page in pages list
            self.pages_grid_list.append(page_btns_grid_widget)                # +++

        next_page_button = QPushButton('next')
        next_page_button.clicked.connect(self.next_page_action)

        previous_page_button = QPushButton('previous')
        previous_page_button.clicked.connect(self.previous_page_action)

        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(previous_page_button, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

#        self.h_layout.addLayout(self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages])         # ---
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages])          # +++

        self.h_layout.addWidget(next_page_button, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.show()

    def get_coordinates_btn_clicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        print('coordinates: {}'.format(button.text()))                           # +++ button.text()

    def next_page_action(self):
        self.count_pages = self.count_pages + 1
        if self.count_pages < len(self.pages_grid_list):
            self.new_page(self.count_pages)
        else:
            self.count_pages = len(self.pages_grid_list) - 1

    def previous_page_action(self):
        self.count_pages = self.count_pages - 1
        if self.count_pages >= 0:
            self.new_page(self.count_pages)
        else:
            self.count_pages = 0

    def new_page(self, count_pages):                           # +++
        widget = self.h_layout.takeAt(1).widget()
        widget.hide()
        self.h_layout.insertWidget(1, self.pages_grid_list[count_pages])  
        self.pages_grid_list[count_pages].show()     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Mas, você saberia dizer porque do jeito não funciona?